# Get sum of consecutive rows in one row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table as:

```
Emp_id  Emp_Name    Department     Score
123     Raju            D1          300
124     Ravi            D2          400
125     Annie           D3          600
126     Ajay            D4          200
127     Amey            D5          500
128     Akil            D6          100
```

I need output as

- Sum of Score of row1 and row2 in row1
- Sum of Score of row2 and row3 in row2,
- and so on

So the output should be:

```
700
1000
800
700
600
```

I need the output through a SQL query and not a procedure or something else.

Comment: Which database/version are you using

Comment: @Utsav,I am using Oracle 11g

Comment: Also I see that you have asked many questions earlier which people answered, but you never accepted them. Read [What to do if someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and close all your previous questions first.

Comment: I didnot know we can accept answers.Will do now.

Comment: Sure. And do it for your previous questions as well. Go you your profile and see the Questions tab. Without you accepting it, the question remains open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `Lead` function, which will show second row with first row and so on. Name it `nxt_score`. Then you can add `score` and `nxt_score` to get your output. You will also need `nvl` as for last row, the `nxt_score` will be null. So in that case, it will add the score with `0`.

Remove other columns from select clause if you want.

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  score + nvl(nxt_score, 0) AS cum_score
FROM 
    (SELECT
      t.*,
      LEAD(score, 1) OVER (ORDER BY emp_id) AS nxt_score
    FROM table1 t
    ) t1
```

Comment: it worked very well. Could you please explain me. I am pretty new to this.Are there any functions similar to this?What are they called so that I can learn them now

Comment: I gave the explanation in the answer. Please let me know if you have any doubt on it.

Comment: ,Please tell me where I can get similar fuctions. I donot know that something like LEAD exists itself. So i want to learn such functions. What are they called?

Answer (score 5):

It is very easy to do this with an analytic function that uses a sliding window from the current row to the next one (`ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING`):

```
SELECT Emp_id, Emp_Name, Department, Score, sum(Score)
  OVER (ORDER BY Emp_id ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) sum
FROM score;
```

When executing this query on your data the result is as follows:

```
123 Raju    D1  300 700
124 Ravi    D2  400 1000
125 Annie   D3  600 800
126 Ajay    D4  200 700
127 Amey    D5  500 600
128 Akil    D6  100 100
```

See [Database SQL Language Reference, Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) for further details.

Comment: Better solution than mine.